# need to add char to string for print to printer, in C# using WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to add char  to string for print to printer, in C# using WinForm

i need this:

```
escBoldOn       = chr(27) + chr(69) + chr(1);  // Bold On
escBoldOff      = chr(27) + chr(69) + chr(0);  // Bold Off
```

i try this:

```
line += (char)27 + (char)69 + (char)1 + "test";  //Bold ON
line += (char)27 +  (char)69 +  (char)0 + "test";  //Bold OFF
```

but its print me   `97test96test` and i need it in bold

Comment: "its not good" is not a good description of your problem. What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: You want to print a string in bold? Printer.FontBold could do that if you are using it.

Comment: u can do this by applying your way to each character separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
line += string.Concat((char)27, (char)69, (char)1, "test");
```

Your expression:

```
line += (char)27 + (char)69 + (char)1 + "test";  //Bold ON
```

can be also written as:

```
line += ((((char)27 + (char)69) + (char)1) + "test");
```

operator + on two chars returns integer:

```
var a = 'a'; var b = 'b';
Console.Out.WriteLine((a + b).GetType()); // System.Int32
```

So you end up with expression:

```
line += (97 + "test");
```

operator + on integer and string returns string

So finally this is interpreted as

```
line += "97test"
```